# react-native-firebase/auth [auth/app-not-authorized]

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

While updating the version from 12.7.3 to 14 or above directly the OTP is not sent and gets the following error.
[auth/app-not-authorized]This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.

Verified that package name and SHA-1 and SHA-256 are correct for both developing and production environments. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: try to re-download google-service.json and replace with existing.

Comment: Tried this. But not working. Getting the same error again.